# How can I pre-render a react app in gulp/node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, gulp

### How can I programmatically render a react app in gulp and node 12?

I taking over and upgrading an old react (0.12.0) app to latest. This also involved upgrading to ES6. The react code itself is done, but we also need to prerender the application (The app is an interactive documentation and must be crawled by search engines).

Previously, the gulp build process ran browserify on the code and then ran it with vm.runInContext:

```
// source code for the bundle
const component = path.resolve(SRC_DIR + subDir, relComponent);

vm.runInNewContext(
  fs.readFileSync(BUILD_DIR + 'bundle.js') + // ugly
    '\nrequire("react").renderToString(' +
    'require("react").createElement(require(component)))',
  {
    global: {
      React: React,
      Immutable: Immutable,
    },
    window: {},
    component: component,
    console: console,
  }
);
```

I am suprised it worked before, but it really did. But now it fails, because the source uses ES6.
I looked for pre-made solutions, but they seem all targeting old react versions, where react-tools was still around.

I packaged the special server-side script below with browserify & babel and then ran it using runInNewContext. It does not fail but also not output any code, it just logs an empty object

```
import React from 'react';
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server';
import App from './index';

const content = renderToString(<App />);
```

I found tons of articles about "server-side rendering", but they all seem to be about rendering with express and use the same lines as the script above. I can't run that code directly in gulp, as it does not play well with ES6 imports, which are only available after node 14 (and are experimental).

Comment: Switch the imports to requires, then?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, you made me realize I forgot to show the gulp render task - which was not rendering the server-side script but the app component! So I was attempting to execute an app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I failed to show the gulp-browserify task, which was rendering the app component directly, instead of the server-side entrypoint script above. In case anyone ever needs to do this, here is a working solution.

Using `vm.runInNewContext` allows us to define a synthetic browser context, which `require` does not. This is important if you access `window` anywhere in the app.

src/server.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server';
import App from './index';

const content = renderToString(<App />);
global.output = content;
```

above script serves as entry point to browserify. Gulp task to compile:

```
function gulpJS() {
  const sourcePath = path.join(SRC_DIR, 'src/server.js');
  return browserify(sourcePath, { debug:true })
    .transform('babelify', {
      presets: [
        ["@babel/preset-env", { targets: "> 0.25%, not dead" }],
        "@babel/preset-react",
      ],
    })
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source('server_output.js'))
    .pipe(buffer())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true}))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
    .pipe(dest(BUILD_DIR));
}
```

The generated file can now be used by later tasks, e.g. to insert the rendered content into a HTML file.

```
const componentContent = fs.readFileSync(path.join(BUILD_DIR, 'server.js'));
const context = {
  global: {
    React: React,
    Immutable: Immutable,
    data: {
      Immutable
    },
  },
  window: {
    addEventListener() { /* fake */ },
    removeEventListener() { /* fake */ },
  },
  console,
};

vm.runInNewContext(componentContent, context);
const result = context.global.output;
```